# load single byte from label to register in arm64 using GAS

Tags: assembly, arm64, gnu-assembler

I would like to use the `ldrb` instruction to load a single byte from memory into a register. However, this does not seem possible if the 2nd operand is a label. A complete minimal reproducible commented example:

```
// GNU Assembly, aarch64 Linux

.data

.equ SYS_EXIT, 93
.equ SUCCESS, 0

CHAR:
    .byte 1

.text

.global _start

_start:
    // none of these work, but why?
    // ldrb w19, CHAR       // invalid addressing mode at operand 2
    // ldrb w19, =CHAR      // invalid addressing mode at operand 2
    // ldrb w19, [CHAR]     // 64-bit integer or SP register expected at operand 2
    // ldr w19, CHAR        // loads 4 bytes instead of 1 byte

    // I have to do this but it's verbose and clunky
    ldr x20, =CHAR
    ldrb w19, [x20]
    // is there any way to coalesce the above 2 instructions into 1?

    mov x8, SYS_EXIT
    mov x0, SUCCESS
    svc 0
```

Ideally I'd like to write `ldrb <reg>, <label>`, e.g. `ldrb w19, CHAR`, and have it just load a single byte from `CHAR`'s memory address like I would expect, instead of throwing an assembler error.

Comment: Not the fault of the assembler, apparently `LDRB` does not take a PC-relative offset.

Comment: [Check out what a compiler does](https://godbolt.org/z/j1jeEs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Siguza says, the CPU simply doesn't have any such instruction.  The only addressing modes supported by `LDRB` are register base + register-or-immediate offset, as you can see in the architecture reference manual (required reading for any assembly programmer).  The assembler is quite rightly refusing to assemble a nonexistent instruction.

So you can't achieve what you want in a single instruction; you need two.  However, those two instructions can be more efficient than what you've chosen.  The standard idiom [used by compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/j1jeEs) seems to be:

```
adrp x19, CHAR
ldrb w19, [x19, #:lo12:CHAR]
```

Here `adrp` will load `x19` with the top 52 bits of the address of `CHAR`; the instruction encodes the offset of the page on which `CHAR` is located, relative to the page of the current instruction (this offset is computed and filled in by the linker or loader), so that it produces position-independent code.  Then the low 12 bits of the address are added via the offset in the addressing mode (which is limited to 12 bits); this offset is known at link time, since load-time relocation happens only in units of pages or more.  Note that we can use the same register for the address computation as for the destination of the load; we don't need a second one.

Compared to your approach, this avoids the need to use the literal pool, saving you an extra load from memory and 8 bytes of space in the pool.

If you still find it too "verbose", you could always wrap it in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

> none of these work, but why?

Because the only load instructions that take a PC-relative literal are `ldr` and `ldrsw`:

[image: screenshot of table C3-16]

See Table C3-16 in the [ARMv8 Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest).